# Decrypting a small Message using RSA with a Private Key

Tags: encryption, rsa, reference-request

If I have a private key of (`43`, `341`). What would be the steps I need to take to decrypt a small message using RSA? I have looked online and everything seems very confusing. Any tips or advice would be helpful.

I have gotten this far:

1. p=31  q=11
2. p*q=341
3. O(n)=(31-1)(11-1)=300
4. e=7
5. (43*e)%300=1  e=7
6. public key (e,n) (7,341)
7. Private Key (d,n)(43,341)
8. encryption of m=2   c=2^7%341=128
9. decryption of c=128 m=128^3%341=2

What would be the next step to decrypt a message?

Comment: Is (43,341) a 2-tuple or the number 43,341?

Comment: Its the numbers 43 & 341

Comment: Ok, that's a good start. The next step is to review what you know about RSA encryption. Do you understand how you encrypt a message using an RSA public key?

Comment: I have the algorithm to generate the public key and private keys from 2 long prime numbers but after generating the keys Im lost

Comment: Well there's your first step :) You have to understand encryption before you understand decryption hehe. Where are you getting lost with understanding encryption? Do you understand the math behind why we can use the public key to encrypt?

Comment: You can check the freely available book [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac). Chapter 8.2 has a full description and example.

Comment: I have read up on it and followed all the steps in the algorithm. What would I do next to decrypt the message.

Comment: 1. p=31  q=11
2. p*q=341
3.O(n)=(31-1)(11-1)=300
4.e=7
5.(43*e)%300=1  e=7
6. public key (e,n) (7,341)
7. Private Key (d,n)(43,341)
8. encryption of m=2   c=2^7%341=128
9. decryption of c=128 m=128^3%341=2

Comment: In step 9, why are you raising to the 3?

Comment: In step 9, where you write m=128^3%341=2, I think you mean m=128^43%341=2, because your private key is 43, not 3.

Comment: Note that instead of 43 you could use 13 as your private exponent, and it would work just as well. Can you tell me why?

Comment: step 9 is by factorization and if we need with out factorization then methon  by n

Answer (score 2):

In step 9, you decrypted the ciphertext, 128, to the original message, 2. That's it. You're done with the toy example of naive RSA encryption/decryption.

Using RSA in real life, you would apply padding, such as [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_Asymmetric_Encryption_Padding) (also known as PKCS#1v2), to your message before raising it to the e power modulo n.

If the plaintext you're trying to encrypt is quite short, say less than half as long as the RSA modulus, you might agree with the recipient to apply RSA directly to the message.

Normally the plaintext isn't that short. What you do is encrypt and MAC the plaintext with a symmetric cipher and MAC algorithm that you agree on with the recipient, using a randomly selected key for the symmetric cipher and a randomly selected key for the MAC. Then you use RSA with a 'message' consisting of the key to the symmetric cipher and the MAC key. You send your recipient all of (A) the RSA ciphertext, (B) the ciphertext from the symmetric cipher, and (C) the MAC. The recipient decrypts the RSA ciphertext (A), unpads it and obtains the keys for the symmetric cipher and the MAC. With those in hand, verifies the MAC (C) of the ciphertext (B) and finally decrypts the symmetric ciphertext (B) to obtain the plaintext.